# Help fixing errors in C# "A ref or out argument must be an assignable"

Tags: c#, .net, windows, compiler-errors

Here's a block of code I'm having errors with:

```
    public static bool Flash(Form form)
    {
        return (Win2000OrLater && FlashWindowEx(ref Create_FLASHWINFO(form.Handle, 15, uint.MaxValue, 0))); //A ref or out argument must be an assignable variable

    }

    public static bool Flash(Form form, uint count)
    {
        return (Win2000OrLater && FlashWindowEx(ref Create_FLASHWINFO(form.Handle, 3, count, 0))); //A ref or out argument must be an assignable variable
    }
    private static extern bool FlashWindowEx(ref FLASHWINFO pwfi);
    public static bool Start(Form form)
    {
        return (Win2000OrLater && FlashWindowEx(ref Create_FLASHWINFO(form.Handle, 3, uint.MaxValue, 0))); //A ref or out argument must be an assignable variable
    }

    public static bool Stop(Form form)
    {
        return (Win2000OrLater && FlashWindowEx(ref Create_FLASHWINFO(form.Handle, 0, uint.MaxValue, 0))); //A ref or out argument must be an assignable variable
    }

    private static bool Win2000OrLater
    {
        get
        {
            return (Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major >= 5);
        }
    }
```

The error message is:

> A ref or out argument must be an assignable

Comment: The first error: you're probably passing an object that cannot be changed, a constant or something like that. Second Error: is that function declared public?

Comment: ask one question at a time. Your first question is explained by the error message. Make a local variable, put he flash window info in it and pass that by ref.

Comment: [form.Handle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.handle(v=vs.80).aspx) has no setter

Comment: Please post your 2nd question as a new question, so that other users can benefit, also, posting fuller source code would help.

Comment: it's not declared public, sorry I'm new to C#, how do I make it like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your first errors, you need to introduct the FlashWindow as a variable so for example

This:

```
public static bool Flash(Form form)
{
    return (Win2000OrLater && FlashWindowEx(ref Create_FLASHWINFO(form.Handle, 15, uint.MaxValue, 0))); //A ref or out argument must be an assignable variable
}
```

becomes:

```
public static bool Flash(Form form)
{
    if (Win2000OrLater)
    {
        FLASHWINFO fi = Create_FLASHWINFO(form.Handle, 15, uint.MaxValue, 0);
        return (FlashWindowEx(ref fi));
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I'll put the second part as another question since other users will benefit, thanks a lot for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

You need an assignable variable for a ref or out param.

```
FLASHWINFO fwi = Create_FLASHWINFO(form.Handle, 15, uint.MaxValue, 0);
FlashWindowEx(ref fwi);
```